# Error when creating new partition on /dev/sda, "No free sectors available"

Tags: partition, fdisk, oracle-linux

I have a VirtualBox Linux Guest (Oracle Enterprise Linux 6) and I recently expanded hard drive from 50Gb to 100Gb and then used GParted to resize to use the newly added 50GB (as this was unallocated). All this was successful but then I came across the error "No free sectors available"

```
[root@oralab1 Desktop]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_oralab1-lv_root
                       45G  4.2G   39G  10% /
tmpfs                 7.9G  100K  7.9G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             485M   55M  405M  12% /boot
[root@oralab1 Desktop]# 
[root@oralab1 Desktop]# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 107.4 GB, 107374182400 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 13054 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000ef7c4

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1          64      512000   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2              64       13055   104344576   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/vg_oralab1-lv_root: 49.0 GB, 48997859328 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 5956 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000


Disk /dev/mapper/vg_oralab1-lv_swap: 4160 MB, 4160749568 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 505 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

[root@oralab1 Desktop]# 
[root@oralab1 Desktop]# 
[root@oralab1 Desktop]# 
[root@oralab1 Desktop]# 
[root@oralab1 Desktop]# fdisk /dev/sda

WARNING: DOS-compatible mode is deprecated. It's strongly recommended to
         switch off the mode (command 'c') and change display units to
         sectors (command 'u').

Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/sda: 107.4 GB, 107374182400 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 13054 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000ef7c4

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1          64      512000   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2              64       13055   104344576   8e  Linux LVM

Command (m for help): n
Command action
   e   extended
   p   primary partition (1-4)
p
Partition number (1-4): 3
No free sectors available

Command (m for help): ^C
```

I need to expand and use the full 100GB.

Attachment ([image: pvs, vgs and lvs output])

Comment: You have already a 100gb size sda2. (`104344576   8e  Linux LVM`)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the output of `pvs`, `vgs` and `lvs`.

Comment: Stephen, I have provided the [pvs vgs and lvs output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvZcy.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

you already have all the disk at sda2, as I can see at `pvs` command (size 99Gb, 50GB free)

So you only have to increased the lvs partition that already have.

```
lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/vg_oralab1-lv_root
```

and resize at os level:

```
resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg_oralab1-lv_root
```

now you are using all the size in your lvm filesystem.

Comment: Just a note: both of these commands can be done while the OS is running normally.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create new partition you may use **lvcreate** instead of **fdisk /dev/sda**. Follow the bellow step in command line

Step 1:

```
 #  lvcreate --name lvname --size lvsize vgname
 # ex lvcreate --name lv_home --size 30G vg_oralab1
```

Step 2: Format the Logical volume(lv) by any linux filesystem

```
 # mkfs.xfs /dev/vg_oralab1/lv_home
```

Step 3: Create mount point and mount the lv

```
# mkdir /lv_part
# mount /dev/vg_oralab1/lv_home  /lv_part
```

Step 4: Check the partition by

```
# df -h
```

NOTE: For permanent mount give entry in **/etc/fstab**